# Flowtype named types

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Is there a way to get the name of a flow type as a string at run time? If not, is there another way to handle this problem:

I want to make a generic type but switch over which type it is. For example, I have a FormField type like this

```
type FormField<T> = {
  label: string,
  required: boolean,
  value?: T,
  status?: ValidationStatus,
  touched?: boolean,
  validate?: (T, FormData) => boolean
}
```

However, I want to do logic based on the type. For example, if it is a string field, render a text field. If it is a boolean field, render a checkbox. Right now my solution is to make multiple types like this:

```
type TextFormField = {
  type: 'text',
  label: string,
  required: boolean,
  value?: string,
  status?: ValidationStatus,
  touched?: boolean,
  validate?: (string, FormData) => boolean
}
type BoolFormField = {
  type: 'bool',
  label: string,
  required: boolean,
  value?: boolean,
  status?: ValidationStatus,
  touched?: boolean,
  validate?: (boolean, FormData) => boolean
}
type FormField = TextFormField | BoolFormField
```

And then switch over the `type` field. However, this leads to a lot of copy-and-paste and other uglyness. Is there a more elegant way to handle this? (I can't switch over `typeof value` because it could be `undefined` and I don't want the way the page is rendered to change if the value of an input gets set to something weird.

Comment: > Is there a way to get the name of a flow type as a string at run time?
Nope, sorry. Why is switching over the `type` field such a burden? Can you give some example code relating to that?

Comment: @JamesKraus switching over the `type` field is actually really good, the issue is more in having to have so many types (I'd also like to have enums, numbers, etc). I also get a lot of errors like `property 'status' is missing in mixed`

Comment: You could use classes and test type with `instanceof`. Not sure if this helps. Can you show an example of what you would like to have?

Comment: i think add constructor to every field to create dynamically elements ,i hope it help you.